# How to show background image above border?

Tags: css

I have  tag with 25px padding and 15px border from left. And I am using arrow background image in it. Is it possible to show this background image above the border?

Here is HTML

```
<a id="arrow">List</a>
```

CSS

```
a#arrow { 
    background:url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-back-20.png') no-repeat;
    padding-left:25px;
    border-left:15px solid #f1f1f1;
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/t5U9u)

Comment: there is an easy possible solution here is using multi-background feature, instead of using `border-left`, you can try using `linear-gradient` to mimic the `border-left`, specify it as the second background, while the first is your arrow image which will lay on top of the linear-gradient background, check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/t5U9u/4/) Of course multi-background is not supported by some old versions of browsers especially ***IE***. However if it was me, I would never care about that.

Comment: You would have to achieve the border in some other way.. because you cannot have a background of an element be on top of the same elements border.. you either have to split into two elements (can use :after), or use multiple backgrounds and mimic a border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your background to the :after element as a method

**CSS**

```
#arrow:after {
    content:'';/*enable after element*/
    position: absolute;
    top: px;/*position of the background*/
    left: px;/*position of the background*/
    background: url(img/your-bg.png)  no-repeat;
    width: px;/*width of the background*/
    height: px;/*height of the background*/
}
```

And dont forget to add position:relative to the #arrow

Comment: Yes, this will work but I want it do it with other way because :after is supported by IE8.

Comment: @Gajen Do you need support IE7+ or earlier?

Answer (score 1):

You can use background position to view your image.
 here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5U9u/5/)

Your css should be

```
a#arrow{ background:url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-back-20.png') no-repeat;
padding-left:25px;
border-left:15px solid #f1f1f1;
background-position: -36px;
}
```

Comment: this wouldn't put the image above the border

Comment: Did u check the fiddle.. 
it is not showing because the size of the tag for which the background-image property is defined is smaller.. Thats y i asked u to adjust it with background position.. add a property like 
border: 1px solid black to know the size of your tag and increase its width and height so that u can see full image

Comment: @nidhin, can you create me a fiddle ?

Comment: there is a fiddle in my answer ryt. It isnt working?

Comment: @Gajen i have edited my answer.. check the fiddle now

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. Checkout this jsfiddle.net/umxn4
I want that arrow image above left red border.

Comment: its not possible with background-image. You have to set it as a separate image tag if u want that image to be displayed above your border-left

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-position` property with values in pixels to show them on top.

For instance,

```
background-position: xxpx (for left-right) xxpx (for top-bottom);
```

***PS: xx is a dummy value, which you can replace with actual numbers.***

Comment: I've tried background-position but background image is showing behind that border. Is there another way?

Comment: also add, `position:relative;` with `z-index:999;` It will then work. - @Gajen